# asp.net mvc ajax crazy

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

From a page Index.cshtml, i have a very simple ajax call

controller1 and controller2 have the same action:

```
public ActionResult abc(string name)
    {
        return new JsonResult()
        {
            Data = new
            {
                success = true,
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            }
        };
    }
```

$(document).ready(function ($) {

```
    $.ajax({

        url: '@Url.Action("abc", "controller1")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { name: 'John' },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
                alert("ok");
            }
            else {
                alert(result.error);
            }
        }

    });
});
```

> > not work

however using exactly the same syntax, just change the controller, it works !!!.

abc action is the same.

```
$.ajax({

        url: '@Url.Action("abc","controller2")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { name: 'John' },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
                alert("ok");
            }
            else {
                alert(result.error);
            }
        }

    });
```

it drives me crazy, don't know what happen. On a new project, i tried the same code, it works perfectly, but not on my current work.

Comment: do you have any specific kind of route definitions for controller1 actions ?

Comment: try to watch the Global.asax, imo

Comment: Somewhere along the line the two scenarios are not exactly the same :) you just need to have a good look to find it.  The fact that you have `JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` suggests that you may previously have used a `GET` method and not `POST`.  Are you sure that you do not have `[HttpGet]` on the method in `Controller1`?

Comment: thanks, i forgot that i use the same keyword in Routing. My bad !!